# Permanently removing a JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to run [jake](http://github.com/jcoglan/jake) on OS X 10.6.4 but get the message `Narwhal on Rhino requires Java 1.5 or higher.  You have JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:.-Xmx512m`. This is left over from a previous project where someone told me to set it to get Flash to export without dying.

I have java 1.6 installed. The JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS seems to be the issue. I removed it using `unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`. This worked until I reopened Terminal. The `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable comes back.

Any ideas on how I can permanently get rid of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably set it in the `.bashrc` or `.profile` file in your homedirectory, remove it from there and you should be fine when you start a new terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately I have neither of those files in my home directory. I have .bash_profile which doesn't contain any java declarations. I checked the bashrc file in /etc but there's no java stuff in their.

Is there anywhere else that it could be set?

Comment: There is also the possibility that you created a ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist file to set it. Otherwise, if you are not in a hurry you could search your whole filesystem for the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS string: use `grep -rI JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS /` (-r = recursive, -I = ignore binary files) .. that will take quite some time to execute though.

Comment: Good suggestion. There was indeed a ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist file and it contained an entry of JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m. It did require that I remove it then restart but it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have that variable in your environment. All you need to do is to remove it from env:

1. Just write `unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` in your terminal.
2. Set that line in the ~/.bashrc file to be sure that it will not abuse you next time you run console.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are on Windows:

```
C:\dev>java -jar helloworld.jar
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor='Sun Microsystems Inc.'
Hello World
```

Suppress by:

1. Run `setx JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS ""`
2. Restart the terminal window

Result:

```
C:\dev>java -jar helloworld.jar
Hello World
```